# XML: what does exclamation mark mean in <! some text>

Tags: xml

Smililarly to the question: [XML what does that question mark mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119165/xml-what-does-that-question-mark-mean)
what does exclamation mark mean in e.g. below from [Meaning of - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743250/meaning-of-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8).?

I have not been able to find it here on stackoverflow or via web search. The link https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp from the answer the the question above on question mark mnetioned only one example of `<!` that is comment `<!--`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider it the generic prefix for an 'element of the XML syntax' (ad hoc term). The grammar does not assign a non-terminal to the sequence `<!`, it only occurs in conjunction with some other text ( eg. `<!DOCTYPE`, `<!ELEMENT`, `<!--` ). Note how that differs from processing instructions generically prefixed with `<?`.

The authoritative reference are the W3C standards for XML ([v 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), [v 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/)).

Comment: `non-terminal` was new (or long forgotten)  term for me, I found that link https://gerardnico.com/code/compiler/nonterminal. Looks like correct meaning, if not, please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

Constructs in the XML prolog beginning with `<!` are called *markup declarations*. XML supports element declarations (`<!ELEMENT ...`), attribute declarations (`<!ATTLIST ...`), entity declarations (`<ENTITY ...`), and notation declarations (`<!NOTATION ...`). These appear within a *document type declaration* (`<!DOCTYPE ...`). The syntax of markup declarations is derived from SGML, the larger markup meta-language of which XML (and HTML syntax) is a subset. SGML has additional types of markup declarations such as short reference use/map declarations (`<!USEMAP ...`/`<!SHORTREF ...`) for parsing Wiki syntax into markup, and link set declarations (`<!LINK ...`/`<!IDLINK ...`) for use within *link process declarations* (`<!LINKTYPE ...`), another type of declaration set SGML has in addition to document type declarations, and which can be used to express stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE` starts a Document Type Declaration, `<!--` introduces a comment.

There exist CDATA sections, Element Type Declarations, Attribute-List Declarations, Entity Declarations, Notation Declarations, and Conditional Sections also, that all start with `<!`.

You can read more about them in the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/).